# Is there a way to list the names of excel sheets that contain a value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel workbook with several sheets. The first sheet is called Master sheet and there I have a table with several names on column B (with a title first "Name").

Some of these names appear on the other sheets.
Is there a way I can search for these names on the other sheets and list them in the next columns of the Master sheet?

For example, if in column B of the master sheet I have John Smith and he is in sheet A and sheet B but not in sheetC, I would like to have Sheet A and Sheet B listed next to John Smith in the master sheet
This for all names listed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: This is a slow solution and not recommended for large datasets. It is slow. Turning off automatic formula updates will help.**

This is a very slow and clunky way to do it but it *does* work so long as your data is not so large that you run out of memory.

Say you have a workbook with four sheets: Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, and Sheet4.

Sheet1 has a list of names and the other sheets have some data in some limited range. In my example, I've limited the search to the first 1,000 rows. When I tried to do 10,000 rows, I got "out of memory" errors. I also tried searching A:Z instead and that worked, too.

Sheet1 has "John" in the cell `A2`. Sheet2 and Sheet4 have "John" in then somewhere. Sheet3 does not. I put this formula into the cell `Sheet1!A3`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$Z,$A2),"Sheet2",""), IF(COUNTIF(Sheet3!$1:$1000,$A2),"Sheet3",""), IF(COUNTIF(Sheet4!$1:$1000,$A2),"Sheet4",""))
```

It's mostly just some variant of this bit over and over, once for each sheet:

```
IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$Z,$A2),"Sheet2","")
```

... and then we join all the results together into a list. That formula counta all the instances in `Sheet2!A:Z` where the value is "John". If the result is more than 0, that's treated as true so the overall results is "Sheet2". Otherwise, it's just an empty string.

You could also make a helper column, one for each sheet name. Have this snippet in each one, and the textjoin to combine all those results. This will get slower and slower the more instances you have.

Comment: If you use `SUMIF` instead of `SUM` it should be a bit faster.